# How did they know where to find the next Horcrux?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter

When anyone destroyed a *Horcrux* in the *Harry Potter* movies, how did they know where the next *Horcrux* is?

Was there a map or something?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174827/can-a-horcrux-be-tracked-magically

Answer (score 4):

- The Diary

  They didn't search for it. Harry found it and destroyed before even knowing Horcruxes existed.
- The Ring

  Dumbledore investigated Riddle's life and important places in order to find it.
- The Locket

  Dumbledore investigated Riddle's life and important places in order to find it.  He found it's hiding location but it had already been replaced with a copy. The trio found the locket in Grimmauld Place previously without knowing what it was. They investigate from there to find it's current location.
- The Cup

  Dumbledore theorized that this object was a horcrux. They find it because the Lestranges panicked when they saw the sword that was supposed to be in Gringots.  This gives away the horcrux location.
- The Tiara

  Dumbledore theorized that this object was an horcrux. They find it by interrogating the ghost.
- The Snake

  Dumbledore implies that the snake is important in a discussion with Snape. He didn't tell Snape that the snake was an horcrux (or what an horcrux was), but states it in a way that Harry would understand. I don't remember how Dumbledore found or (more probably) guessed this.
- The last one

  Dumbledore guessed that Harry was an unwanted Horcrux. He told Snape who then 'told' Harry.

In summary: Dumbledore did all the heavy work. Harry and friends were mostly lucky.

Comment: I know what the Horcruxes were. But I don't know how they found those. So tell how did they find those rather than what they are.

Comment: @dna I believe Dumbledore tells Harry about Nagini being a Horcrux during their meeting at King's Cross, and they already knew where Nagini was at that point. I don't recall how Dumbledore himself found out, though.

Comment: People who haven't seen the movie yet aren't reading the answers to this question. And if they do, they want to hear an actual answer. I thus removed the unnecessary spoiler blocks.

Comment: The snake theory came from the fact that Harry could see what the snake was doing when it attacked Arthur Weasley, just as he could see and feel Voldemort's thoughts.